# MySQL transaction doesn't stop at error

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I am learning to use transactions with MySQL and it doesn't seem to be working as it should.

I created some test code:

```
$db->query('START TRANSACTION;');
$db->query('DELETE FROM test1 WHERE id=4'); 
$db->query('DELETE FROM ttest2 WHERE id=5');  
$res = $db->commit();
```

where "ttest2" was a deliberate error (the table is misspelled).

With normal queries, $res would be false and the query would fail. But when I run the transaction, the first delete occurs, it ignores the second, and $res is still true. I thought transactions would not allow any queries to occur unless they all occurred correctly. Why did it return true and how do I catch an error in PHP?

Comment: "I thought transactions would not allow any queries to occur unless they all occurred correctly." Without the word 'correctly' you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the [rollback](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html):

> These statements provide control over use of transactions:
>
> START TRANSACTION or BEGIN start a new transaction.
>
> COMMIT commits the current transaction, making its changes permanent.
>
> ROLLBACK rolls back the current transaction, canceling its changes.
>
> SET autocommit disables or enables the default autocommit mode for the
>   current session.